# Laravel installation does not know php term

Tags: php, laravel

I have copied laravel project files into my wamp/www/test folder.

I have also downloaded `composer.exe` for windows

I have set my php variable

then when I execute the following command to get started, it does not work and says does not the term php

```
cd c://wamp/www/test
composer install
```

And here is what I have appended to the environment variable:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your terminal after adding the path to your System Variables?

Or maybe you didn't use ***;*** to separate the new path you added from the already existing ones.

Comment: I changed / to \ and then it begins installation. However it says you should enable openssl while I have already enabled it

Comment: Did you restart wamp after enable openssl?